# Bucketing data and selecting only some of the bucketed values

Tags: sas

Say I wish to calibrate on only data values where within each category the values have a frequency of greater than or equal to 10. (This is a simplification of how the data I have is set out in my SAS table, there is a reason why the same value for the same category appears in different rows, **in the actual data set there are 4 categories and hundreds of thousands of value observations**)

```
  Category        Value                Frequency
  A             -1                       6
  A             -1                       7
  A             -0.5                     4
  A              0.1                     12
  B             -1                       9
  B             -0.9                     6
  B             -0.9                     5
  B             -0.5                     14
```

So in the example above for Category A the values -1 and 0.1 would be calibrated on because they have a frequency of 13 and 12 respectively, which is greater than or equal to 10 but -0.5 would not. However, for category B  the values -0.9 and -0.5 would be calibrated on (frequency=11,14). Different categories are to be calibrated on separately.
I'm trying to use SAS to select only the values which have a frequency greater than or equal to 10 within each category.

It's probably best  to start with trying to select one value before it can be extended to the rest. If I call the above dataset 'Categorised' and the new one I am trying to create 'Calibrated', I have got as far as:

```
data Calibrated;
     set Categorised;
     if Category="A" and Value= -1 then new = sum(Frequency);
run;
```

But this just generates an extra column called 'new' with the same entries for frequency for the value of -1 in the 'Categorised' data set. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like below using proc sql.

```
data have;
input 
Category $       Value                Frequency;
datalines;
A             -1                       6
A             -1                       7
A             -0.5                     4
A              0.1                     12
B             -1                       9
B             -0.9                     6
B             -0.9                     5
B             -0.5                     14
;

proc sql;
create table have_to_calibrate as
select * from have
group by category, value
having sum(frequency)> 10;
```

Comment: My data set seems to be too large to use Proc SQL. Can I use a data step instead?

Comment: Hundreds of thousand of rows should not be an issue for PROC SQL.

Comment: Tested this exact scenario, 800,000 rows processed in under 1 second (0.37) with SAS UE which runs on 1 core and 2GB of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't indicated whether in your output you want (a) all original records whose frequency aggregate satisfies your condition or (b) only the unique (category,value) pairs for which the condition is met.

If you want (a), the SQL solution already offered by Kiran is good and is the tersest solution I can think of. However, it you want it in a DATA step, it can be done as well. First, let's assume your data is sorted by (category,value), as it appears to be. Then you can code what is called the double DoW-loop:

```
data want (drop = _:) ;               
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.value) ;
    set have ;                        
    by category value ;               
    _fsum = sum (_fsum, frequency) ;  
  end ;                               
  do _n_ = 1 to _n_ ;                 
    set have ;                        
    if _fsum > 10 then output ;       
  end ;                               
run ;
```

If your data is not sorted, a hash table can be used to achieve the effect:

```
data want (drop = _:) ;                      
  dcl hash h (ordered:"a") ;                 
  h.definekey ("category", "value") ;        
  h.definedata ("_fsum") ;                   
  h.definedone () ;                          
  do until (last) ;                          
    set have end = last ;                    
    if h.find() ne 0 then _fsum = frequency ;
    else _fsum + frequency ;                 
    h.replace() ;                            
  end ;                                      
  do until (0) ;                             
    set have ;                               
    h.find() ;                               
    if _fsum > 10 then output ;              
  end ;                                      
run ;
```

If you want (b), i.e. only the distinct (category,value) pairs, the SQL (in the form offered) will not work. The DATA step will if you reduce the code for the sorted input data solution to the following:

```
data want (keep = category value) ;   
  do until (last.value) ;
    set have ;                        
    by category value ;               
    _fsum = sum (_fsum, frequency) ;  
  end ;                               
  if _fsum > 10 ;                     
run ;
```

And for the unsorted data (the hash approach):

```
data _null_ ;                                       
  dcl hash h (ordered:"a") ;                        
  h.definekey ("category", "value") ;               
  h.definedata ("category", "value", "_fsum") ;     
  h.definedone () ;                                 
  do until (last) ;                                 
    set have end = last ;                           
    if h.find() ne 0 then _fsum = frequency ;       
    else _fsum + frequency ;                        
    h.replace() ;                                   
  end ;                                             
  h.output (dataset:"want (where = (_fsum > 10))") ;
  stop ;                                            
run ;
```

Regards,

Paul Dorfman